# How to add an object to a Dictionary without declaring a separate variable for it?

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct

I'm having trouble working through how to add an item to a dictionary that I declare within the dictionary.Add argument.

I have a struct called option with 2 strings.

I have a dictionary within a class called Contains.

I want to accomplish

```
        option Change = new option("change","change");
        Contains.Add(contains.Count + 1, Change);
```

on the same line.  Is this possible?

I tried

```
        Contains.Add(contains.Count + 1, option Change = new option("change","change"));
```

and it did not work.

I'm sure the answer is simple, I just haven't been able to figure it out using google or this site after 30 minutes of searching.  Sorry!

Comment: you have to declare it first: `option Change;  
Contains.Add(contains.Count + 1, Change = new option("change","change"));`

Comment: Your question's not very clear, but if you want a variable, called `Change`, that contains a copy of the `option` struct that was added to the dictionary, you need to do it on two lines.

Comment: It's hard to accomplish if you need a reference to the object you just added. Why do you want to change this? For readability it is fine, but it will not make an impact on your program's runtime performance.

Comment: you can write as well `Contains.Add(contains.Count + 1,new option("change","change"));`. You don't have to declare and instantiate object before adding if you will not use it later(after add to your dictionary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do either

```
Contains.Add(contains.Count + 1, new option("change", "change"));
```

or

```
option Change = new option("change", "change");
Contains.Add(contains.Count + 1, Change);
```

the first code block creates a new instance of `option` on the spot and adds it to the dictionary. the second code block creates a new variable of type `option` (a reference to an instance of `option`) and adds it to the dictionary. you cannot declare a new variable within the call to the Contains.Add method, that is illegal.

PS: the C# language specification documents [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29), [local variable declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742%28v=vs.71%29), and [statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx). in case you want to read up on how to declare variables in C# these will be the most relevant topics to you (but probably a bit hard to grasp from the formal C# language specification, so I'd recommend picking up a good book on how to get started with C# and look for some tutorials like those on MSDN).

Comment: I am new to Dictionary use, and I did not understand that the dictionary.add value does not have to be declared.  Thanks!

Comment: @SoylentGreen - it sounds like you have some confusion about the difference between variables and values. A decent introductory programming book *ought* to cover this difference.

Answer (score 4):

Just

```
Contains.Add(contains.Count + 1, new option("change","change"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following :

```
Contains.Add(contains.Count + 1, new option("change", "change"));
```